# How do I convert something of "string*" to "const string&" in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, constants

For example, if I have the following:

```
void foo(string* s)
{
    bar(s); // this line fails to compile, invalid init. error
}

void bar(const string& cs)
{
    // stuff happens here
}
```

What conversions do I need to make to have the call the bar succeed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change it to:

```
bar(*s);
```

Comment: How would I do it the other way? Turn const string& into string*?

Comment: @Petr: Your risk casting away the `const`-ness, but if you know what you are doing, `const_cast<string *>(&s)`

Answer (score 4):

```
void foo(string* s)
{
    bar(*s);
}
```

`s` points to a string, and `bar` requires a (reference to a) string, so you need to give `bar` what `s` points to.  The way you spell "what `s` points to" is `*s`.

Answer (score 2):

When converting a pointer to a reference it is important to make sure that you are not trying to convert a NULL pointer.  The compiler has to allow you to do the conversion (because in general it can't tell if it is a valid reference).

```
void foo(string* s)
{
    if(0 != s){
      bar(*s);
    }
}
```

The * operator is the inverse of the & operator.  To convert from a reference to a pointer your use & (address of).  To convert a pointer to a reference use * (contents of).